# Spring security - access private endpoints without authentication

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

i am creating my backend with microservice architecture using spring. i have an eureka server, a zuul gateway server and other microservices which communicate with each other using feing proxy.. what i want to know is how to check security and authorization only once per request? what i mean, if i have a microservice **A**  which calls a microservice **B** through a private endpoint, how to check security and authorization only for the first call of microservice **A** and ignore the security for the microservice **B**? knowing that security check must be made when the call is direct for the same endpoint of microservice **B**.

for example, when authenticating, the **Login** microservice with a public **authentication()** endpoint, call the **Account** microservice to get user information through a private **getUserInfo()** endpoint.
in this case, security check must be ignored for the 2 endpoints, because **authentication()** endpoint is public.

the second example, when validating authentication, the **Login** microservice with a private **validateAuthentication()** endpoint, call the same private endpoint **getUserInfo()** of the **Account** microservice. in this case, the security check must be made for the **validateAuthentication()** endpoint, and ignored for **getUserInfo()** endpoint.

knowing that **getUserInfo()** endpoint can be called directly, and in this case the security validation must be made.

This is my **SecurityConfig** class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter()
{
    companion object
    {
        val PUBLIC_END_POINTS = arrayOf(
                "/auth/identification"
        )
    }


    override fun configure(http : HttpSecurity)
    {
        http
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(*PUBLIC_END_POINTS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .addFilterBefore(AuthenticationFilter() , UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
    }
}
```

and this is my **AuthenticationFilter** class

```
class AuthenticationFilter : OncePerRequestFilter()
{

    override fun doFilterInternal(request : HttpServletRequest , response : HttpServletResponse , filterChain : FilterChain)
    {
        // validate token and user's info
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}
```

Some one can help me? i spent a lot of time searching in the internet and i did not find a solution..

Comment: Can you add and clarify your question a bit more? It seems you are mixing two different concepts one is statelessness and other is authentication on different microservices.

Comment: @Ricardo I just want security validation to be done once per request when an endpoint calls another endpoint from the proxy .. if the first endpoint is public, and the second is private, I don't want verification be done on the second endpoint which is private .. if the first endpoint is private and the second is private also, I want the verification to be done only on the first endpoint

Comment: I don't know your architecture but you can only do the authentication and authorization on the gateway and all of your microservices are private. I don't think I'm understanding your doubt correctly. It is better for you to clarify (what you have, what you want and also share your current architecture because I think its more an architectural than code issue)

Comment: sorry for few help, but googling for "spring securing microservices" or "spring microservices sso" gives "promising" results (e.g. https://dzone.com/articles/build-secure-microservices-in-your-spring-rest-api)

Answer (score 1):

You must provide authentication only through the gateway and remove the spring security from other microservices. You must execute this pulic microservices in an intranet and expose to internet just the gateway. You must implement an AuthenticationEntryPoint and set it in the HttpSecurity configuration. You should configure as private your microservices endpoints, except the one for authentication.